# How to generate new web page programmatically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, seam, seam2

I want to create a small forum using JSF/Seam.

When I post articles, a new page should be generated using that article name. For example, I posted an article named "How to Learn Java", then the new page should be named like "how-to-learn-java.xhtml". How can I implement this function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bad approach.
I am not aware about seam. 
But better way will be keeping the articles in DB and get it rendered in one template. Create a data access POJO for your article which is having fields like 
1.articleHeader.
2.articleName.
3.articleContent.
4.articlePics
5.articleLinks

In the template use these fields to display the page your way.

Url will look like 
http://yourdomain.com/articles.jsf?id=23472305
where 23472305 is the db id for the article

Comment: He can always use a filter (like http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to forward http://yourdomain.com/articles/23472305/how-to-learn-java.xhtml to http://yourdomain.com/articles.jsf?id=23472305 (transparent to the user) kinda like SO works.

Comment: @SimonArsenault agreed

Comment: That filter is exactly what I need!